# Reactjs styled-components when having props can't get theme color

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Here is the code

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import theme from "styled-theming";

const color = theme("mode", {
  default: "blue",
  primary: "tomato"
});

const border = theme("mode", {
  default: "yellow",
  primary: "purple"
});

const Container = styled.div`
  display: block;
  color: ${color};
  border: 3px solid ${props => (props.textAlign ? "none" : `${border}`)};
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container theme={{ mode: "primary" }} textAlign={"center"}>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </Container>
      <Container theme={{ mode: "default" }}>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a working example  https://codesandbox.io/s/old-http-649gc

The issue is here `border: 3px solid ${props => (props.textAlign ? "none" : ${border})}` no matter if I have `textAlign` or not, I can't get theme `${border}` color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `styled-theming` returns a function that is later processed by the expression to provide a value.

You can view the function by logging the values:

```
console.log(border, `${border}`)
```

The first `border` variable is a function while the second has been converted to a string by virtue of it being inside ``.

An easy solution would be:

```
border: 3px solid ${props => (props.textAlign ? "none" : border)};
```

`border` variable is already inside a JavaScript expression being inside the `${}`, so variable can used directly.

[Fixed Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-56901265-5hbbe)